# SQL query with JOIN, WHERE, GROUPBY, COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is an example of the schema I am working with.

How can I return the `id` and `name` of all users who have a permission, but DO NOT have a matching certification for that permission?

For example, the query would return 0, john in this case, since john has the "delete" permission, but does not have a matching "delete" certification.

(This schema is arbitrary and contrived, I'm just trying to get at the syntax/select logic for this query)

```
users
=====
id  name
--------
0   john
1   joe

user_permissions
================
uid permission
--------------
0   'edit'
0   'delete'
1   'edit

user_certs
==========
uid cid
-------
0   'edit'
1   'edit'
```

I've tried, this, and I know the last line is wrong.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, name FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_permissions users ON users.uid = user_permissions.uid
LEFT JOIN user_certs ON users.id = user_certs.uid
WHERE (user.permission = 'delete')
GROUP BY id, name
HAVING (COUNT(user_certs.cid = 'delete') = 0)
```

Comment: Looks like you got a rogue ) in your where clause.  Also, do you have control over the schema?

Comment: I do not have control. Fixed the extraneous paren, that was a typo in my initial submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all the permissions that doesn't have a matching certificate, then group on the user:

```
select
  u.id,
  u.name
from
  users u
  inner join user_permissions p on p.uid = u.id
  left join user_certs c on c.uid = p.uid and c.cid = p.permission
where
  c.uid is null
group by
  u.id,
  u.name
```

Comment: Thanks, my example was bad but this got me close enough to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Bud you are right.

The alias user dies not exist.

Comment: Sorry, just a typo in my example.